# CMake + Qt Creator: Add header files to project files

Tags: c++, cmake, include, qt-creator, projects-and-solutions

If I have `.h` and `.cpp` files in the directory `src`, where the `.cpp` files include the `.h` files, using these commands in CMake:

```
aux_source_directory(src SRC_LIST)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC_LIST})
```

And opening that CMake file in Qt Creator, gets all the files (sources + headers) in the list of project files (the file tree on the left by default).

Now, on the other hand, if I put all the `.h` files in a directory `include`, and use this:

```
include_directories(include)
aux_source_directory(src SRC_LIST)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC_LIST})
```

The header files disappear from the project files!

How can I keep the header files in that directory, and still have them listed in Qt Creator's project files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add my header files always explicit to avoid any surprise.
But on MacOS using QtCreator 4.2.0 and cmake 3.7.1 I can't reproduce your issue.

However I recommend to use following structure to know which files are within project and to trigger update of cmake's data during update of CMakeLists.txt.

In project/CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_subdirectory(src)
include_directory(include)
add_executable(foo ${SRC_LIST})
```

In project/src/CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(SRC_LIST
    ${SRC_LIST}
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/a.cpp
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/b.cpp
    PARENT_SCOPE
)
```

Comment: `${SOURCES}` vs `${SRC_LIST}` will not work. Those are two different variables.

Comment: @Torbjörn: Thanks. I fixed.

Answer (score 7):

You shouldn't use `aux_source_directory()` for your task. That command is for something different. Just list the source files (or put them in a variable).

You shouldn't use `include_directory()` for defining include directories any more. This command will just populate the `-I` flag of the compiler. Define a variable with the header files and add that to the executable.

In case you don't want to list every file manually, use `file(GLOB ...)`. But be aware of the caveats mentioned frequently all over the web with using that command.

Afterwards, tell CMake to populate the `-I` flag only for that executable with the `include` directory. That way, other targets don't get polluted by includes, they shouldn't use.

```
set(SOURCES
    src/main.cpp
    src/whatever.cpp)
set(HEADERS
    include/whatever.h)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES} ${HEADERS})
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC include)
```